# To which directory images or files should be uploaded in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, filesystems, fs

In Meteor, what should be the directory for uploading images or files?

**Currently this is my directory where I am uploading all the Images:**

```
meteorApp/public/uploads/images/
```

But whenever I upload images, it refreshes my client. Its because Meteor is continuously looking for a change in its directory or files. So where should I set my uploads directory to?

Comment: This is a recurring question but the `/public` folder is used for Assets like favico, humans.txt etc. and your Meteor app should not update this folder.

I would personally go for [CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to put files in a place Meteor does not care about: hidden folder (.name), ignored folder (name~), or folder outside of Meteor directory.

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740790/dynamically-insert-files-into-meteor-public-folder-without-hiding-it/17743042#17743042).

Comment: If I put upload outside of Meteor directory, how will I access images by http url? like we display images in content etc

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003222/meteor-application-access-files-outside-its-root-directory

Comment: Thanks alot. That url in your answer helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use the Collection FileSystem package which provides a complete file management solution like uploading, downloading, synchronization, copying, etc.

It can be then plugged to local filesystem or even Amazon S3.

Here is the repo : https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS. You need to add first the main package :

```
meteor add cfs:standard-packages
```

And then the storage adapter you want to use:

- Local filesystem (directory like /public, /uploads)

  `meteor add cfs:filesystem`
- Amazon S3 (my fav)

  `meteor add cfs:s3`
- GridFS

  `meteor add cfs:gridfs`
- Even Dropbox!

  `meteor add cfs:dropbox`

The doc is really complete, you may find what you are looking for! :)